# Passing pointer of automatic variable to DMA function

Tags: c, pointers, scope, stm32, dma

Question is specifically about the STM32 microcontrollers using DMA.

Consider the following:

```
while(true){
    randomStuff();
    uint16_t distance;
    getDistance(&distance);
    HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA((uint8_t*)&distance, 2);
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

Now normally when using a single thread this would be fine since the execution follows a linear flow and distance will not go out of scope before the called function finishes. However this is a special call to a DMA peripheral that doesn't block and allows execution to continue, and thus go out of scope for the "distance" variable.

Inside this DMA function I can see the pointer gets copied:

```
huart->pTxBuffPtr = pData;
```

After that it calls this where TDR is supposed to be destination address:

```
HAL_DMA_Start_IT(huart->hdmatx, (uint32_t)huart->pTxBuffPtr, (uint32_t)&huart->Instance->TDR, Size);
```

It's not clear to me at what point the usage of my pointer ends and when my scope here ends. Is this safe to do?

I want to avoid using dynamic allocation because it's an embedded system, which has a tendency to get fragmented and crash if you overuse dynamic allocations.

Comment: You're correct to be suspicious, it's not safe.  Just make it `static uint16_t distance` and your scope will remain.

Comment: ... but if you do make it `static`, make sure that you don't reinitialize another transfer with the same buffer before the first one have finished.

Comment: You should add something like `wait_DMA_not_busy()` after `doOtherStuff()` (or before `getDistance()`) otherwise `distance` could be overridden not depend on static/auto storage type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size)
```

takes the pointer pData which is copied immediately in

```
huart->pTxBuffPtr = pData;
```

But that value is not actually used or sent because after few lines you can find:

```
tmp = (uint32_t*)&pData;
```

and then:

```
HAL_DMA_Start_IT(huart->hdmatx, *(uint32_t*)tmp, (uint32_t)&huart->Instance->DR, Size);
```

So your pointer is used when *&pData* is copied into *tmp* and then is still used in the DMA call all the way down until the DMA is configured with:

```
hdma->Instance->M0AR = SrcAddress;
```

thus this is not safe since from there the next thing you know is the interrupt of TX complete from the DMA. So in the end when you return from

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA
```

and branch to

```
doOtherStuff();
```

You may still be using the pointer. As already mentioned declaring it static is a solution because the internal state machine is preventing to get problems if you recall the DMA transfer again with *&distance*.